# How do I select a default font?

Tags: init-file, fonts

I recently installed Arch Linux on my new laptop. Shortly, afterwards, I also installed the X Window System and Emacs 24. I like the DejaVu Sans Mono font so I added it  to my `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12
emacs.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12
```

The font works perfectly for my terminal emulator URxvt, however when I start emacs this message popped up:

```
$ emacs
     Font `xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12` is not defined
```

Apparently Emacs was built with xft, as shown below:

```
$ ldd `which emacs` | grep libXft
     libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f8498c37000)
```

How can the font not be defined in emacs?

Comment: This was the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781098/how-to-set-frame-font-in-emacs/22787669#22787669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me, I had not installed the `ttf-dejavu` package in Arch Linux. I got sidetracked by the fact that urxvt did not give me an error message, which lead me to believe that it was something wrong with emacs.

Comment: If this is the answer then please accept it (you can accept your own answer).

Comment: There is a waiting period of 36 or 48 hours or something like that before an original poster can accept his/her own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the font backend for the font naming syntax, probably because programs like `urxvt` require you to prepend `xft:` for specifying fonts by their family name.  See its manual for more details.

Emacs only accepts [XLFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description)s in that file, so try `-*-DejaVu Sans Mono-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*` instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the same error: `Font -*-DejaVu Sans Mono-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-* is not defined`. I also tried to define the font in my .emacs file as such: `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :height 200)` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default font by customizing your [`default-frame-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html).  In your `.emacs` file, add the following:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-12"))
```

Comment: This gives the same error message but in the message box in emacs: `Font DejaVu Sans Mono-12' is not defined `